# Python converting latin1 to UTF8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-2.7, latin1

In Python 2.7, how do you convert a latin1 string to UTF-8.

For example, I'm trying to convert é to utf-8.

```
>>> "é"
'\xe9'
>>> u"é"
u'\xe9'
>>> u"é".encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa9'
>>> print u"é".encode('utf-8')
Ã©
```

The letter is é which is LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (U+00E9)
The UTF-8 byte encoding for  is: c3a9
The latin byte encoding is: e9

How do I get the UTF-8 encoded version of a latin string? Could someone give an example of how to convert the é?

Comment: Did you read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) yet? If not, you should!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have, but encoding is always a bit confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To decode a byte sequence from latin 1 to Unicode, use the [`.decode()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode):

```
>>> '\xe9'.decode('latin1')
u'\xe9'
```

Python uses `\xab` escapes for unicode codepoints below `\u00ff`.

```
>>> '\xe9'.decode('latin1') == u'\u00e9'
True
```

The above Latin-1 character can be encoded to UTF-8 as:

```
>>> '\xe9'.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
'\xc3\xa9'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> u"é".encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa9'
```

You've got a UTF-8 encoded byte sequence. Don't try to print encoded bytes directly. To print them you need to decode the encoded bytes back into a Unicode string.

```
>>> u"é".encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
u'\xe9'
>>> print u"é".encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
é
```

Notice that encoding and decoding are opposite operations which effectively cancel out. You end up with the original `u"é"` string back, although Python prints it as the equivalent `u'\xe9'`.

```
>>> u"é" == u'\xe9'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

> concept = concept.encode('ascii', 'ignore') concept =
>   MySQLdb.escape_string(concept.decode('latin1').encode('utf8').rstrip())

I do this, I am not sure if that is a good approach but it works everytime !!